# Continuous extension of positive functions on a C-embedded set.

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is a discrete, closed and $C$-embedded subset of a completely regular Hausdorff space $X$. Then how can we prove that for every continuous function $f:A\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, there exists a continuous extension $F:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ of $f$.

Comment: What does "$C$-embedded" mean? My google-fu failed me.

Comment: A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called C-embedded in $X$ if every real-valued continuous function on $A$ can be extended to a continuous function on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called C-embedded in $X$ if every real-valued continuous function on $A$ can be extended to a continuous function on $X$.

So we know that we can extend any continuous $f \colon A \to (0,\infty)$ to a continuous $F\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, and the only problem is that the extension might attain values $\leqslant 0$.

If $f$ is strictly positive on $A$, then $g\colon A\to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$g(a) = \log f(a)$$

is a continuous real valued function on $A$, and hence can be extended to a continuous real-valued $G \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $F(x) = e^{G(x)}$ is the desired strictly positive continuous extension of $f$.